# Unable to validate reactive form on submit in angular 7

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I am trying to submit a form blank to trigger validation. I have also researched on following topic but failed to achieve. It is giving me no errors or any output

On the submit function I am calling following function to marked form input as touched

```
validateAllFields(formGroup: FormGroup) {
Object.keys(formGroup.controls).forEach(field => {
  const control = formGroup.get(field);
  if (control instanceof FormControl) {
    control.markAsTouched({ onlySelf: true });
    control.updateValueAndValidity();
  } else if (control instanceof FormGroup) {
    this.validateAllFields(control);
  }
});
}
```

Form group initialization

```
buildForm(): void {
this.userForm = this.formBuilder.group({
  first_name: [
    this.user.first_name,
    Validators.compose([
      Validators.required,
      Validators.minLength(2),
      Validators.maxLength(20)
    ])
  ],
  middle_name: [this.user.middle_name],
  last_name: [
    this.user.last_name,
    Validators.compose([
      Validators.required,
      Validators.minLength(2),
      Validators.maxLength(20)
    ])
  ],
  email: [
    this.user.email,
    Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.email])
  ],
  mobile_number: [
    this.user.mobile_number,
    Validators.compose([
      Validators.required,
      Validators.maxLength(10),
      Validators.pattern('^[1-9][0-9]{9,9}$'),
      validMobileNumber
    ])
  ],
  password: [
    this.user.password,
    Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(8)])
  ],
  c_password: [
    this.user.c_password,
    Validators.compose([Validators.required, confirmPassword])
  ],
  user_type_id: [this.user.user_type_id, Validators.required]
});
this.userForm.valueChanges.subscribe(data => this.onValueChanged(data));
}
```

Comment: how do you see errors? Did you `console.log(formGroup)` on submit and see if it contains errors? You have checks for form errors? As far as I know, there is no need for form controls to be touched for a form to be in error, that may be condition you would be using to display errors

Comment: When did you call this function?

Comment: @QuanVO (ngSubmit) event

Comment: @xyz I am not getting any error. I wanted to programmatically touched all the form input so that user can know.

Comment: show me your ngIf condition for error in html

Comment: @BibekShakya Please show your form group initialization

Comment: markAsTouched doesn't trigger the validator. Additionally add .updateValueAndValidity() to the control.

Comment: @BenjaminIfland I have edited my question by adding updateValueAndValidity still no luck

Comment: Can you add your html template?